# overriding the default session time in ASP.NET and IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, session

How can I change the default session time in an ASP.NET website to something user defined - perhaps 1 hr?

I assume the default session time is 20 mins..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change in your web.config for application level like..

```
<sessionState timeout="40"></sessionState>// note this is minutes
```

and you can also change in your machine.config as well for all application

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [set the `Timeout` property in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx):

```
<sessionState 
    mode="InProc"
    cookieless="false" 
    timeout="60" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are rigth...
If the setting is not explicitly stated, the default timeout value will be 20 minutes.

**timeout Setting** controls the length of time a session is considered valid. The session timeout, which is specified in minutes, is a sliding value. i.e. on each request, the timeout period is reset to the current time plus the timeout value. 
Here's an example of how the setting is specified:

**timeout="60"**